# Reduction of expression algebraically

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I have asked this question before and it helped me get a little further, but not at a solution.

I have to algebraically reduce the expression:

$\sinh(2 \cdot \sinh^{-1}(y))$

Now i had the idea of using the hyperbolic addition formulas, but i got some convoluted answers. The earlier question i asked helped me on the way a bit with this:

$\sinh(2x) = 2 \sinh(x) \cosh(x)$ where $x = \sinh^{-1}(y)$

$= 2 y \cosh(x)$.

Now $\cosh(x) = \sqrt{1 + \sinh(x)^2}$.

But i have no idea of where to go from here. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are finished. The answer is $2y\sqrt{1+y^2}$. There is no useful further simplification.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How does the $sinh(x)^2$ become $y^2$?

Comment: We have $\sinh(\sinh^{-1}(y))=y$. It would have been better to use $\sinh^2(x)$, or maybe $(\sinh(x))^2$. Maybe your notation $\sinh(x)^2$ was the cause of the confusion.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.